# Product of Dedekind cut

Tags: real-analysis

If $ v* = \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : r < v\}, w*= \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : r < w\} $ and $n,m$ positive integers such that $ v= n$ and $w = m/n$. Then $v*, w*$ are Dedekind cuts.

I want to show that the product of the cuts, $(v*)(w*)$ is equal to the set $ (vw)* = \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : r < vw\}=\{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : r < m\}$.

My approach is to show that $v\ast w * \subset (vw)*$ and the converse, $(vw)* \subset v*w*$, then $ (vw)* = v*w* $.

However, I don't know how to define the product. Consider $v_1 \in v* $ and $w_1 \in w*$. Then surely the product can satisfy $v_1 w_1 > vw$ if $v_1, w_1 < 0$. How does one get around this?

Comment: well, you can define it on $\mathbb{R}^+$, but I don't think you can define it in a natural way on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How have you defined the product of two positive cuts? Using the standard definition yields the result you're looking for immediately. The standard definition: $\alpha{},\beta{}\in{}\mathbb{R}^+\implies{}\alpha{}\beta{}=\{q|q\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,q\leq{}ab\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,a,b\in{}\mathbb{Q}^+\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,a\in{}\alpha{}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,b\in{}\beta{}\}$.